# Higher loss while training a matrix factorization problem using larger batch size

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recommendation-engine

First I want to say thank to anyone consider reading this question, and I want to sorry if my question is so stubborn, and for my poor English.

So currently I'm working on a recommendation system problem, and my approach was to use matrix factorization with implicit feedback using BPR ([arXiv:1205.2618](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2618)). Somehow, I discovered that when I trained my model (BPRMF), using a large batch size (in this case 4096), resulted in a poorer BPR loss compared to when I used a smaller batch size (1024). [my training log on few epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXjBD.png).

I noted that higher batch size resulted in faster training time as it can utilize GPU memory more efficiently, but the higher loss is something maybe I'm not so willingly to trade. As far as I know, a large batch size bring much more information for the gradient descent step to take a better step, so it should help with convergence, and usually problem with large batch size is in memory and resource, not with loss.

I have did some research about this, and saw that [Large Batch Training Result in Poor Generalization](https://eprints.lib.hokudai.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2115/71558/3/Tomoumi%20Takase.pdf) and [here another](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/what-is-the-trade-off-between-batch-size-and-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neu), but in my case, it was poor lost while in training.

My best guess is that using a large batch size, then take the mean of the loss make the gradient flow to the user and item embedding lower by the mean ( 1 / batch size) coefficient, make it hard to escape local maxima while training. Is it the answer in this case ? (However, I saw that recent study has show that local minima is not necessarily bad, so ...)

Really appreciated anybody help me answer why large batchsize ended up with anomaly results.

Side note: Might be another stupid question, but as you can see in the code below, you can see that the l2 loss is not normalized by batch size, so I expected it to at least double or quadruple when I multiply batch size by 4, but that seem not to be the case here in the log above.

Here is my code

```
from typing import Tuple

import torch
from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter
import torch.nn.functional as F

from .PretrainedModel import PretrainedModel


class BPRMFModel(PretrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, n_users: int, n_items: int, u_embed: int, l2:float,
                 dataset: str, u_i_pretrained_dir, use_pretrained = 0, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(n_users=n_users, n_items=n_items, u_embed=u_embed, dataset=dataset,
                         u_i_pretrained_dir=u_i_pretrained_dir, use_pretrained=use_pretrained, 
                         **kwargs)

        self.l2 = l2
        self.reset_parameters()
        self.items_e = Parameter(self._items_e)
        self.users_e = Parameter(self._users_e)
        

    def forward(self, u: torch.Tensor, i: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        u = F.embedding(u, self.users_e)
        i = F.embedding(i, self.items_e)
        return torch.matmul(u, i.T)

    def CF_loss(self, u: torch.Tensor, i_pos: torch.Tensor, i_neg: torch.Tensor) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        #u, i_pos, i_neg shape is [batch_size,]

        u = F.embedding(u, self.users_e)
        i_pos = F.embedding(i_pos, self.items_e)
        i_neg = F.embedding(i_neg, self.items_e)
        pos_scores = torch.einsum("ij,ij->i", u, i_pos)
        neg_scores = torch.einsum("ij,ij->i", u, i_neg)

        # loss = torch.mean(
        #     F.softplus(-(pos_scores - neg_scores))
        # )
        loss = torch.neg(
            torch.mean(
                F.logsigmoid(pos_scores - neg_scores)
            )
        )

        l2_loss = (
            u.pow(2).sum() +
            i_pos.pow(2).sum() +
            i_neg.pow(2).sum()
        )
        
        return loss, self.l2 * l2_loss
    def get_users_rating_for_each_items(self, u: torch.Tensor, i: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self(u, i)
    def save_pretrained(self):
        self._items_e = self.items_e.data
        self._users_e = self.users_e.data
        return super().save_pretrained()
```

PretrainedModel is just a base class helping me with the save and load model weight

Really appreciated anyone who bear with me till this end.

Comment: Are you using `SGD`? if so maybe `Adam` can help dealling with multiple loss.

Comment: Also have you try fiddling around with optimizer's parameters like learning rate or momentum? Normally if loss goes up reduce learning rate could somewhat help. If loss oscillating then reduce momentum should work.

Comment: I'm using Adam optimizer with lr at 1e-2, using CosineAnnealingWarmRestarts lr scheduling with t0 at 10 and tmul at 2. Have been fiddling around with learning rate at 1e-3 and 1e-4 but they are too small, learning was too slow in those case. Loss is not oscillating that much so ...., but i will try changing momentum. I have also tuned l2 to see if it was just too high but seem might not be the case here.

Comment: If low LR make converging too slow then that means it still learn properly right? Maybe the schedule is the problem?

Comment: I don't think so, with low batch size (1024) the schedule help the model escape some shallow minima, eventually achieved really good metrics, but the same is not applied to large batch size (4096)